# Why did Sherlock make "VR" on wall with gunshots?

Tags: sherlock-holmes-2009

In [Sherlock Holmes (2009)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes_(2009_film)), while testing his [suppressor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppressor) Holmes makes **VR** on wall which stand for Victoria Regina, the Royal Cypher (monogram) of then-reigning Queen Victoria. Around 1892, because Tower Bridge was half constructed then as shown in movie)

**But why?**

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure where the Tower of London dates came from, but it was built in 1078, last major changes in 1399... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_London

Comment: ...and why not?

Comment: @Tetsujin: Corrected. It was Tower Bridge.

Answer (score 12):

## No reason is ever given.

The fact is that the "V.R." is taken from a description by Dr. Watson of Holmes' mannerisms from *The Musgrave Ritual* by A. Conan Doyle

> I have always held, too, that pistol practice should be distinctly an open-air pastime; and when Holmes, in one of his queer humors, would sit in an arm-chair with his hair-trigger and a hundred Boxer cartridges, and proceed to adorn the opposite wall with a **patriotic V.R. done in bullet-pocks**, I felt strongly that neither the atmosphere nor the appearance of our room was improved by it.

Basically, Holmes did it *because he felt like it*.

The filmmakers merely added it as *canon set dressing*